# How to change format date of bootstrap fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, date, fullcalendar

Hi I want to change the date format in bootstrap fullcalendar. I have the select function active, and when I click into a day, load a modal with the date. The date have this format: Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST  And I want this: 2015-09-28 08:15:00

I'm trying change in parameter value start of select function but I cant, and I don't know where is declared this value:

```
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {

      $('#createEventModal #apptStartTime').val(start);
```

I have read some ways, but I can't do this work:

```
 var formDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
```

How can I change this on first open page with calendar?

Comment: there is no `bootstrap fullcalendar`, the fullcalendar plugin has nothing to do with bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Check the following post, something like below. It may help you.

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(end,'h:mm tt');
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'ddd, MMM d, h:mm tt');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/azmjv/16/